# How can I get the status of multiple kubernetes resources in a single API call?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using the python kubernetes client to control deployment of resources. I'd like to poll the status of multiple resources at once to provide near-realtime feedback on when a given set of resources is available. Right now I have to query each resources individually, which seems excessive on a system where each *set* of resources scales by N users (so if there are 6 resources there would be N(6) requests for a status check).

Is there way to query the API and get the status of all resources that match a given label selector? If not, is there another approach I should consider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> get the status of all resources that match a given label selector?

I started out by seeing how `kubectl` does it, because at high enough verbosity levels, it shows the actual underlying HTTP transactions:

```sh
kubectl --v=8 get deploy,pod  -l app.kubernetes.io/name=something
```

seems to issue two separate `GET` calls, so I believe it is just putting them in flight concurrently and then awaiting the threads.

As for the other half of your question,

```sh
kubectl --v=8 get all -l app.kubernetes.io/name=something
```

does the same thing as the CSV version, but instead appears to do something akin to `kubectl api-resources` (or maybe has a hard-coded list of what it considers `all`?) and *then* does the same thing: putting multiple `GET` in flight and awaiting the threads

You may be interested in exploring how `kubectl rollout status` operates, to see if that might help you. I also tried adding `--watch` to the `get all` and was informed:

> F0730 21:55:36.819494 2887268 helpers.go:115] error: you may only specify a single resource type